# Simpson's rule code

Tags: equation-solving

I could swear I'm doing this correctly but the answer is just off every time for Simpson's rule. Any help?

```
simp[data_, dt_, n_] := (data[[dt]] + data[[dt + dt]] + 
    2 Sum[data[[i]], {i, 2, n - 2}] + 
    4 Sum[data[[2 i - 1]], {i, 1, n/2}])*(dt*1/3)
```

Comment: Please provide runable Mathematica code for your complete example

Comment: simp[data_, dt_, 
  n_] := (data[[dt]] + data[[dt + dt]] + 
    2 Sum[data[[i]], {i, 2, n - 2}] + 
    4 Sum[data[[2 i - 1]], {i, 1, n/2}])*(dt*1/3)where the data set is data={4,5,9,12,16,19,21} dt=2, n=7

Comment: The first two terms `data[[dt]] + data[[dt + dt]]` should be `data[[1]] + data[[n]]` I think!

Comment: it comes out the same just 150 when it should be 146

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
simp[data_, dt_,n_] := (data[[1]] + data[[n]] 
+ 2 Sum[data[[i]], {i, 2, n - 2}] 
+ 4 Sum[data[[2 i - 1]], {i, 1, n/2}])*(dt*1/3)

data = {4, 5, 9, 12, 16, 19, 21}; 
n  = Length[data];
dt = 2;

simp[data,dt,n] (* 150 *)
```